# Keepalived VIP with WireGuard VPN

Tags: vpn, vps, wireguard, keepalived

When WireGuard and KeepAlived are configured, VIP Switches between VPNs.
There is a connection at address 10.0.0.X between the VPS,
But when I try to contact via VIP I get an error.
ChatGPT Advises adding each peer to AllowedIPs

But when I do this, this address will only be assigned to one peer.

```
# cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
PrivateKey = xxx
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32, 10.0.0.100/32
Endpoint = 161.97.128.186:51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32, 10.0.0.100/32 
Endpoint = 91.229.245.198:51820

After restart 

# sudo wg
interface: wg0
  public key: xxx
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: xxx
  endpoint: 91.229.245.198:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.3/32, 10.0.0.100/32
  latest handshake: 8 seconds ago
  transfer: 3.29 KiB received, 4.41 KiB sent

peer: xxx
  endpoint: 161.97.128.186:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.2/32
  latest handshake: 12 seconds ago
  transfer: 1.11 MiB received, 1.35 MiB sent
```

The VIP address turns out to be assigned to only one peer

When KeepAlived assigns VIP to VPS1 and when I try to ping from VPS 2 or 3 I get an error

```
# ping 10.0.0.100
PING 10.0.0.100 (10.0.0.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Required key not available
From 10.0.0.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Required key not available
From 10.0.0.3 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Required key not available
--- 10.0.0.100 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2047ms
```

With this advice, when the VIP is specified at one peer, then there will be a connection to it if at that moment the VIP is with him.

In the example that I pointed above, the address 10.0.0.100/32 is located at VPS3 and if the VIP is there, then there will be a connection to it from VPS1, but if it goes to VPS2 then I will not be able to contact via VIP
to VPS 2 from VPS1

Below I will give my standard configuration without chatGPT advice

VPS 1 conf keepalived

```
# cat /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface wg0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 101
    advert_int 1
    unicast_src_ip 10.0.0.1
    unicast_peer {
        10.0.0.2
        10.0.0.3
    }
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass vTrHveEXSnoIo5NE
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.0.0.100
    }
}
```

WireGuard conf VPS1

```
# cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
PrivateKey = xxx
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
Endpoint = 161.97.128.186:51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32
Endpoint = 91.229.245.198:51820
```

VPS1:

```
# sudo wg
interface: wg0
  public key: xxx
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: xxx
  endpoint: 91.229.245.198:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.3/32
  latest handshake: 8 seconds ago
  transfer: 3.29 KiB received, 4.41 KiB sent

peer: xxx
  endpoint: 161.97.128.186:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.2/32
  latest handshake: 12 seconds ago
  transfer: 1.11 MiB received, 1.35 MiB sent
```

VPS2:

```
interface: wg0
  public key: xxx
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: xxx
  endpoint: 38.242.222.170:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.1/32
  latest handshake: 19 seconds ago
  transfer: 25.32 KiB received, 18.43 KiB sent

peer: xxx
  endpoint: 91.229.245.198:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.3/32
  latest handshake: 35 seconds ago
  transfer: 252.19 KiB received, 350.48 KiB sent
```

VPS3:

```
interface: wg0
  public key: xxx
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: xxx
  endpoint: 38.242.222.170:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.1/32
  latest handshake: 1 minute, 18 seconds ago
  transfer: 2.00 MiB received, 1.66 MiB sent

peer: xxx
  endpoint: 161.97.128.186:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.2/32
  latest handshake: 1 minute, 26 seconds ago
  transfer: 489.45 KiB received, 273.22 KiB sent
```

When running keepalived on all VPS

VPS1

```
# ip addr show wg0
8: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.0.100/32 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When VPS 1 stops, it moves on to VPS2, etc.

I'm looking for insights or solutions to ensure the VIP is consistently recognized and accessible across all configured VPS in the WireGuard setup. Any suggestions on why this discrepancy is occurring and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.